# STUSB4500 shutting down when I hook-up my wireless charger

Tags: power-supply, esp32, wireless-charging, usb-pd

I'm using the STUSB4500 to generate 12V, 3A which generally seems to work. I'm configuring the STUSB4500 NVM registers using the SparkFun_STUSB4500.h library and the code looks like so:

```
usb.setPdoNumber(3);
Serial.println("Setting PDO3");
usb.setVoltage(3,12.0);
usb.setCurrent(3,3);
usb.setLowerVoltageLimit(3,20);
usb.setUpperVoltageLimit(3,20);
usb.softReset();
delay(1000);
```

Observation:
When I use GPIO16 of my ESP32 to programmatically connect a [wireless charging unit](https://de.aliexpress.com/item/1005004705036636.html?spm=a2g0o.order_list.order_list_main.22.756d1802yxXHT3https%3A%2F%2Fwww.aliexpress.com%2Fitem%2F1005004705036636.html%3Fspm%3Da2g0o.order_list.order_list_main.22.756d1802yxXHT3&gatewayAdapt=glo2deu) then the STUSB4500 would shut down and the voltage of Vcc immediately drops down to zero. The charging of my mobile phone as such does not seem to be the problem and it's running smoothly after the initial start-up has completed. After start-up and when disconnecting and re-connecting the charging unit, the problem occurs repeatedly.

Question:
Could there be high currents/voltage that force the STUSB4500 to shutdown? Is there a way to monitor the STUSB4500 and are there standard components which could stabilize the circuit, say add something like current-limiter, a diode? I guess a charging coil is an inductive device which can generate currents running back into the PCB, however, I'm not a specialist here and some feedback would be very much appreciated!

Kind regards

PS: As a side-remark, this won't happen when the Vcc output voltage is set to 5V instead of 12V.

[image]
[image]